Не могу поменять цвет фона инпута при фокусе на нем
Не могу поменять цвет фона инпута при фокусе на нем. Инпут импортирован из materializecss. Бекграунд у меня серый, при фокусе на инпуте он становится белый, я бы хотела, чтобы инпут был такого же цвета как и body.
<div className="row">
    <div className="input-field col s12">
      <input
        placeholder="Search"
        type="search"
        className="validate"
        value={this.state.search}
        onChange={(e) => this.setState({ search: e.target.value })}
        onKeyDown={this.handleKey}
      />
      <a
        onClick={() => this.props.searchMovies(this.state.search)}
        className="waves-effect waves-light btn"
      >
        Search
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>



Довольно странно в вопросе про CSS, не показать ни строчки CSS

@Alexey Ten да, точно. Вот,что я пробовала .input-field {
background-color: #212121;
}
.input-field:focus {
background-color: #212121;
}

А остальной код? Хотя проще в инструментах разработчика посмотреть откуда берётся белый фон
